# Connecting to GCM server running at local server

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on push notifications with Google Cloud Messaging(GCM). I am able to setup server and client side following [this tutorial](http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/).

The server runs on Apache Tomcat6.0 (localhost) and Android emulator on Google APIs (API level 17). I have a sender id and API key. When run from the emulator, I get a successful device connection message. Sooner after that, upon sending message from server shows the following error.

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401()
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:211)
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:125)
com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:83)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

From other posts, I understand wrong API key is the culprit. But in my case, I made sure I am using the right one from the API console.

By the way, when I run the emulator, I saw a message 'sending regId to server'. What is the registration id? It is not same as sender id; looks like an encoded one.

Any break through?

**EDIT**

The issue is finally solved! Ant was not properly building the WAR file. So API key hardly gets updated. It was hell of a nightmare to spot the bug. Thanks all for the inputs!

Comment: Emulator does not work.Try with device

Comment: any limitation on device API levels..?

Comment: Its working above 2.2

Comment: Tried on Android 2.2! Same error!

Comment: @SanketPandya GCM works on emulator with Google APIs. I tried with API level 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read the GCM guide:

[GCM guide for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

The sender ID is a constant that is going to be used in the comunication between GCM and your server. The regsitratiomID (regID) is managed by the GCM service when your phone registers to his service.

A better definition:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Sender ID:

> A project number you acquire from the API console, as described in Getting Started. The sender ID is used in the registration process to identify an Android application that is permitted to send messages to the device.

Registration ID:

> An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.

Answer (score 2):

The sender account that you're trying to use to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:

1. Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
2. Invalid project number sent as key.
3. Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
4. Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key
   IPs.

Check that the token you're sending inside the Authorization header is the correct API key associated with your project. You can check the validity of your API key by running the following command:

```
 api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

 curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

If you want to confirm the validity of a registration ID, you can do so by replacing "ABC" with the registration ID. 
Happens when the HTTP status code is 401.

Comment: I have a similar problem w/ a new backend.  Weird part is the curl works, but the autogenerated test page w/ the same api_key gives the 401 error when sending GCM messages.  Puzzling :-P

Answer (score 0):

The Sender ID is the project number what you have created under Google console.

**Registration ID**

When your application registers to the GCM it gets the registration ID. To deliver the message this registration ID will be used by the GCM to identify your device + your application. 
Your android app should send this registration ID to your server so that when server want to send you a message it can tag it with the registration ID, and hence the GCM can deliver it to the right device & right app.

Diagnose whether the registration ID is successfully shared with the server (Get/Post), unless you won't receive any message.